# Customize autofixture property with previously set property

Tags: c#, autofixture

In EF (Entity Framework) it is a common pattern to have a reference to a child entity and the key that the table uses mapped as a property of the parent entity.

When using autofixture in mocking the parent entity I want to find a way to set the primary key of the child entity with the foreign key that was set previously

```cs
_fixture.Build<Parent>()
.With(x=>x.ChildId)
.With(x=>x.Child, 
    _fixture.Build<Child>()
        .With(child=>child.Key,parent => parent.ChildId) //This is not supported in AutoFixture
        .Create()
    )
.Create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information on what you are trying to solve? Are you using EF or EF Core? The solution might be different depending on which one you use.

In the latest version of Entity Framework, AFAIK you would not get a key until you save the entity to the database. In this case you could use one of the database providers Microsoft offers for unit testing. In your case since you use relational features of EF, you might want to use the SQLite provider. Once you have saved your entity the foreign key and navigation properties should contain all the necessary data.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite

If you want an easier between EF Core and AutoFixture you can use the package [EntityFrameworkCore.AutoFixture](https://github.com/aivascu/EntityFrameworkCore.AutoFixture).